# Calculating variance for infinite process

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, means

I have given a process which returns value 1 with probability $(1-k)$ such that $(0<=k<=1)$ and value $0$ with probability $k$. I wanted to calculate variance for random variable $X$ denoting returns of this process.

I calculated it as follows:

$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum xp=(1-k).1+k.0=1-k$
$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\sum xp=(1-k).1^2+k.0=1-k$
$Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = 1-k-(1-k)^2 = 1-k-1+2k-k^2 = k(1-k)$

Now the process is modified to return value $1$ any number of times, each time with the same probability $(1-k)$ and then it can return value $0$ only once with probability $k$. That is the values returned can take form $1,1,...,1,1,0$. The process stops after returning value $0$. There is no limit on how many 1's the process can return. How can I modify above calculations to calculate variance for random variable representing value returned by this modified process? Also are above calculations indeed correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is your variable, let's call it $Y$, the number of trials needed to get to the first $0$?  If so, this is just the standard [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  Or is $Y$ meant to be something else?

Comment: Side note:  if you meant the ordinary Geometric Distribution, then be careful when you read about it.  There are two slightly different things people use that term for, different only by whether one counts the final toss or not.  This is, does $1110$ count as $3$ or $4$ trials?   That ambiguity means you need to take care when using any of the formulas attached to the distribution.

Comment: @lulu You can say that $Y$ is the number of trials needed to get the first 0. In each trial, we will get $1$ with probability $1-k$ and $0$ with probability $k$. So, in this setting, the first question asks for variance for single trial and second question asks for variance for infinite trials. (with infinite trials, we need to consider the last trial resulting 0)

Comment: Ok, so that's the standard Geometric Distribution.  You can read off the variance from the link I sent or, if you want to compute it yourself, it's just a routine exercise in summing infinite series.

Comment: Should have mentioned:  If all you want is the variance, then it doesn't matter which definition is considered.  The two definitions just differ by an additive constant ($1$, as it happens) so they have the same variance.